# Is there simple way to color latex equations?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Is there simple way to color background, highlight some parts of background, equation or some parts of equation?
something like these Latex codes:

1. {\bgcolor{color name}{equation}} or {\bg{color name}{equation}} for background

and

2. {\color{color name}{equation}} or {\mathcolor{color name}{equation}} to color equations

   ---

examples:

- by this code $a^2 + {\color{red} b^2}=c^2$ b^2 must become red
- and by this one $a^2 + {\bg{red}b^2}=c^2$ its background must become red.

Comment: Why not work with these very LaTeX codes? Do they bother you to use them? Don't know about 1 but 2 renders output.

Comment: @MAFIA36790
they don't work for background

$\color{red} a^2$

Comment: use `\color{red}{a^2}`; you need to complete the brace.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 ok I'll check for that,
how about background, How to highlight whole or a part of background?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 
I checked it but don't work for mathematical equations

Comment: What were your codes? `\color{red}{a^2}` works fine at any MathJax-enabled site of SE.

Comment: Also, as I said earlier, you need to complete the braces.